# Max/Min of neurons at the hidden layer of a neural network

Tags: neural-network, mathematics

> We have a neural network with inputs $x_1,...,x_n$, a single hidden layer with neurons $y_1,\ldots,y_m$, and outputs $z_1,...,z_v$. There are no activation functions (i.e., the activation functions are $f(x)=x$). We know that input is between -1 and 1, and we need the outputs to be between -1 and 1 as well. The network has been trained so the weights are all available. Given the weights, find the maximum and minimum values that each $y_i$ can take.

My effort: I thought of a simpler version of it. Let's say we have 2 inputs, 1 node at hidden layer, and one output. Then:

$$y_1=w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 $$
$$z_1=w_1' y_1$$

The maximum for $y_1$ occurs when $x_1=\mathrm{sign}(w_1)$ and $x_2=\mathrm{sign}(w_2)$. So, $y_1 \leq |w_1| + |w_2|$. On the other hand, $-1<y_1 w_1'<1$, so $y_1<1/|w_1'|$. Thus, $y_1\leq \min\{|w_1|+|w_2|,1/|w_1'|\}$. Similary, we can show that $y_1\geq - \min\{|w_1|+|w_2|,1/|w_1'|\}$.

Any idea for the general problem? Has this already been addressed in the literature?